# C++ error: Initialise a vector array member of a struct instance

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a struct as below :

```
typedef struct
{
    vector<int[6]> swaps;
    int score;
}State;
```

Which I then instantitate

```
State s1;
int s1arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
s1.swaps.push_back(s1arr); //this is line number 164 in the error
s1.score=23;
```

Everything below is a huge error. I could not find a similar error anywhere except a location(not on stack overflow where also it was unanswered). The error occurs when i push back into s1.swaps . I would be thankful if someone could help me figure out the error

**Error Log**

```
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\vector:69:0,
                 from SessionOrganizer.h:13,
                 from SessionOrganizer.cpp:7:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc: In instantiation of
'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator
, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int [6]; _Alloc = std::allocator<int [6]>; std::vector
<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int (*)[6], std::vector<i
nt [6]> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = int (*)[6]]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:913:28:   required
from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = in
t [6]; _Alloc = std::allocator<int [6]>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type =
int [6]]'
SessionOrganizer.cpp:164:33:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc:329:19: error: array
must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
    _Tp __x_copy = __x;
                   ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\vector.tcc:335:16: error: invali
d array assignment
    *__position = __x_copy;
                ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\mingw32\bits\c+
+allocator.h:33:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\allocator.
h:46,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:41,
                 from SessionOrganizer.h:10,
                 from SessionOrganizer.cpp:7:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h: In instantiation
 of 'void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::construct(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>
::pointer, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int [6]; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::point
er = int (*)[6]]':
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ext\alloc_traits.h:216:9:   required
from 'static void __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, __gnu_cx
x::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::pointer, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = int [6]; _Alloc = st
d::allocator<int [6]>; __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::pointer = int (*)[6]]'

c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:906:34:   required
from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = in
t [6]; _Alloc = std::allocator<int [6]>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type =
int [6]]'
SessionOrganizer.cpp:164:33:   required from here
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h:130:9: error: par
enthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]
       { ::new((void *)__p) _Tp(__val); }
         ^
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: Arrays aren't copyable or assignable, so they can't really used in a `vector`.

Comment: Why are you writing `typedef struct { ... }State;` in C++? That is unnecessary and perverse. Just write `struct State {...};` instead.

Comment: @JonathanWakely because that crappy statement is pretty common in C and I think was specially designed to make harder using C api in C++.

Comment: @Slava, but a struct containing a `std::vector` cannot be valid C, so there's no reason for the OP to do it here.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I do not justify that use, I just explained where that stucture came from. I agree with you and even more I think this structure should be banned in C as well.

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't store `C array` in vector, it's neither copyable, nor movable, nor assignable. You can use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you can use C++11, or `boost::array` if not. You also can use just `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`.

```
vector<array<int, 6> > swaps;
```

Comment: I can not use c++11 for some reason, I was preferring to use an array instead of vector to save some resizing time for code optimality. I guess i will stick around to using vector of vector then

Comment: @AkashRupela You should use `boost::array` then.

Comment: Or just define your own `array`. Simply `template<typename T, size_t N> struct array { T x[N]; };`  . And then add any methods you need, e.g. `T& at (size_t i) { return x[i]; }`

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is making assignments of its elements internally, this is not defined for arrays. The interesting part of your error is:

> error: invalid array assignment

you will get the same error if you write:

```
int nn[10];
int nn2[10];
nn = nn2;
```

this gives:

```
main.cpp:21:8: error: invalid array assignment
     nn = nn2;
        ^
```

so either use `vector` of `vector`-s or `vector` of `std::array`-s

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use c++11, either use `boost::array` as others have suggested, or use a vector of vectors, and use the array to initialize the inner vector.

Here is the vector of vectors solution - it is similar in structure to what you wanted.

```
#include <vector>

struct State {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > swaps;   // Note the space betweeen the 
                                            // angle brackets due lack of c++11
    int score;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int s1arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    State s1;
    s1.swaps.push_back(
        std::vector<int>(s1arr,                                       // Start of s1arr 
                         s1arr + sizeof(s1arr) / sizeof(s1arr[0])));  // End of s1arr
}
```

Admittedly, this is not as clean as what you had initially, however, this can be made cleaner as follows (if you don't mind giving the array to the constructor):

```
#include <vector>

struct State {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > swaps;
    int score;

    // Default constructor so you can still use the old way
    State {};

    // Constructor which will take an array and create the vector
    template<size_t N>
    State(const int (&array)[N]) 
    {
        swaps.push_back(std::vector<int>(array, array + N));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int s1arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    State s1(s1arr);          // Creates swaps vector

    // Print out the internal swaps vector
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.swaps[0].size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << s1.swaps[0][i] << "\n";
    }
}
```